# Error when acquiring token for scopes: {guid} ClientAuthError: User login is required. For silent calls, request must contain either sid or login_hint

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

Trouble in paradise. I have Azure B2C authentication working locally. However, I deployed to production and now when the page loads I'm getting the following error in the console log.

> Error when acquiring token for scopes: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 ClientAuthError: User login is required. For silent calls, request must contain either sid or login_hint

guid redacted.

Comment: Is this a Web App or a Single Page App? Are you using MSAL? What MSAL version? Are you using Implicit Flow? Can you try with Block 3rd party cookies: Disabled?

Comment: Angular SPA.   "msal": "^1.4.0", "@azure/msal-angular": "^1.1.1". Same result with blocking 3rd party cookies.

Comment: How would I know if I'm using Implicit Flow?

Comment: I have both access tokens and ID tokens checked.

Comment: The only difference I can think of is I'm using https in prod.

Comment: This is implicit flow, and the issue must be due to cookies getting lost in the hidden iframe. Take a look at the network traces in the browser.

Comment: all resources are returning a 200. it is failing the code near "i.name = "AuthError","

Comment: Yes that’s the problem, the iframe will return a http 200 instead of a 302 when the cookies are missing. The browser will block this and the tokens don’t get returned. Compare the working network trace to the non working. The specific request of interest will be to your B2C tenant endpoint with the query parameter “prompt=none”.

Comment: I'm getting this error as soon as the page loads (not when after I click login). In fact I removed the login component.  The endpoint never hits when the error occurs. I suspect this error is occurring when the provider MsalInterceptor is being instantiated.

Comment: Where in your code are you calling acquireTokenSilent()? It should be only called after sign in completed.

Comment: I am not yet calling acuireTokenSilent().

Comment: Your error says the context is a silent call. You should post your code.

Comment: I'm using the code straight out of the sample from active-directory-b2c-javascript-msal-singlepageapp. The problem occurs if I include the following:   providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: MsalInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },

Comment: I discovered that the error in the console only appears when making a api call. Also, the api does not complete.

Comment: API call is what triggers a silent token call. Enable 3rd party cookies on chrome and test again.

Comment: Same result. Any other tips on how to troubleshoot this? I have everything working perfectly locally.

Comment: Hi @lightbulb112 Are you still looking for any help on this.?

Comment: After a lot of work I figured it out

Comment: @lightbulb112 Thank You for the confirmation. I would request you to post your findings as an answer so that it will be helpful to others :)

Answer (score 0):

excluded webapi call from protectedresources